# Suppress a specific android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe

my question is for android os (Galaxy Note 2, rooted device, 4.0.1).

I need to hide the app "Samsung Smart Camera App" permanently, even it tries to go in front or runs after start.

Is there any way to convert an app to a background service?
Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: This belongs on [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings, find the app you want and hit `Disable`.

Comment: Thanks Raghav, but I need this App. I want du suppress it of starting to run in the front. it should always run in background. any idea?

Comment: @apak61 If its your app, just keep all your code in a service. If its not your app, you can't do this.